# Adding HTML + CSS to wix

Tags: html, css, velo

I have HTML file and a CSS file
and I want to add the to wix which accepts only HTML code
when I add the code of the HTML file it gives in the live website me what I want but without any design just a text.

The question is how do I emerge the HTML and the CSS files to make one HTML code & add it to wix
[Here is what I get when I post the code on Wix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DymXA.png)

[I need this design on wix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYXrm.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<style>` tag and put your CSS inside. For example:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      h1 {
        color:red;
      }

      p {
        color:blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Or you can write inline styles directly in your HTML elements, like:

```html
<h1 style="color: red;">
  Hello
</h1>
```